# How to get an element in *ngFor in Angular dynamically without using Js id selector

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that has a bootstrap dropdown, I want to focus on the current week that is set on the dropdown span

I can do it with plain javascript by setting ids, and then using Jquery .focus() method to focus on it, But wanted to know if there is any angular 7/ 7+ way to do it using ViewChildren etc.

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle"
        (click)="focusOnWeek(currentWeek)"
        type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span>Week {{currentWeek}}</span> // currentWeek = 5 need to focus on week 5 <a> tag on click of this span
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li *ngFor="let week of weekList">//weekList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]>
    <a class="dropdown-item"
      Week {{week}} 
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

On Click of Button the Currentweek is focused.

Comment: Is it me or is your ngFor on the wrong element. I'm guessing you would want to have multiple list element with an anchor inside right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ViewChildren` to find the anchor element that you want to focus. First, you set a template reference variable (e.g. `#anchor`) on the anchor elements:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li *ngFor="let week of weekList">
    <a #anchor class="dropdown-item">Week {{week}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the code, you get a reference to the anchor elements with `ViewChildren`:

```
@ViewChildren("anchor") anchorList: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and you set the focus on the anchor that corresponds to the specified week:

```
focusOnWeek(week) {
  const weekIndex = this.weekList.indexOf(week);
  const elementRef = this.anchorList.find((item, index) => index === weekIndex);
  elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e63zih?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

---

If the menu is not immediately visible when the click is made, you can monitor the creation of the menu items with the `QueryList.changes` event. When you detect that the items are visible, you can then set the focus with `currentWeek`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.anchorList.changes.subscribe(() => {
    if (this.anchorList.length > 0) {
      const weekIndex = this.weekList.indexOf(this.currentWeek);
      const elementRef = this.anchorList.find((item, index) => index === weekIndex);
      elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nx5dh2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: I updated the code to use bootstrap instead of SetTimeout to show the drop down https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmvn6g and created a new Stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55692527/5724889

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in html file

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-item" [ngClass]="{'focus': currentWeek === week}" *ngFor="let week of weekList">
        <a>
          Week {{week}} 
        </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
```

add following class in css file

```
.focus{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Make sure you have change detection implemented in focusOnWeek() function.