# How to make scroll element into viewport in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, scroll

This is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_blond97/17ck38dy/)

There is the component with items list in it:

```
class HomeComponent {
    text = 'foo';
    testObject = {fieldFirst:'foo'};
    itemList = [
        '1', 
        '2', 
        '3', 
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8 This one should be scrolled into viewport',
        '9',
        '10',
        '11',
        '12',
      ];

    scrollToElement() {
        // Do scroll there
    }
}
```

It's template:

```
 <button (click)="scrollToElement()">Scroll To 8th Element</button>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList">{{item}}</li>
 </div>
```

And the styles:

```
.wrapper {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

How to make scroll 8th element into viewport of "wrapper" div?

> Update

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659889/how-to-get-an-element-in-ngfor-in-angular-dynamically-without-using-js-id-selec) answer doesn't solve the problem because the question is not how to get element focused, the question is how to scroll to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an element in \*ngFor in Angular dynamically without using Js id selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659889/how-to-get-an-element-in-ngfor-in-angular-dynamically-without-using-js-id-selec)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a unique id to your list elements like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index;" id="list-item-{{i}}">{{item}}</li>
```

And then you can find the element in the click method, and use a method called, scrollIntoView(); like this.

```
scrollToElement() {
    document.getElementById("list-item-7").scrollIntoView();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hn40mub9/5/)

Answer (score 0):

In your element  add in the CSS overflow: auto; this property add scroll in overflow-x and overflow-y.

Example

```js
const $btn = document.getElementById("btn")
const $listItem = document.getElementById("element")

$btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 4000)
  // Here yo calculate the position of your element
})
```

```css
.list {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  list-style-type: none
}

.list .list-item {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 42px;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="btn">Scroll to element</button>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Test 1</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 2</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 3</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 4</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 5</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 6</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 7</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 8</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 9</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 10</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 11</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 12</li>
  <li class="list-item" id="element">Test 13</li>
  <li class="list-item">Test 14</li>
</ul>
```